# Trouble reading data from file into structure

Tags: c

I need help with some code. I have a text file that goes like:

```
131782 Mathematics 59
075160 Mathematics 92
580313 Physics 63
073241 Mathematics 32
487476 Mathematics 73
075160 Physics 98
472832 English 44
...
```

Where there are 80 lines of data which corresponds to 20 students, 4 different subjects and the mark they got for that subject. I want to arrange the data in a manner like this (student ID with their four marks next to their ID):

First table:

```
868717 2 37 49 15
472832 44 88 91 95
580313 91 97 63 78
...
```

So there will be twenty rows of data. Then another table to find the mean of each students marks and to find the mean of each subject in another. Now I don't have a problem with that, what I'm having trouble with is getting my data into the structure. If you look at my code, I'm reading the data in as strings and storing it in a string array of char. I'm still to use `malloc()` to dynamically allocate but I'll do that when I've got this finished. I want to search the array for the student ID and populate their marks using the `update_student()` function but I'm having trouble just how to read in my strings that contain the data into the function because there's three parts to each string, student ID subject and mark. If you look at the end of my code this is as far as I've got. I'm planning on setting up a for loop to ring in the data to the `update_student()` function but can't seem to set the code up.

Does anyone have any ideas to get this data into my structure?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STUDENTS (20)
#define NOBODY_ID (-1)
#define EMPTY_MARK (-1)
#define NO_STUDENT (-1)  

#define SUBJECT_ENGLISH (0)
#define SUBJECT_MATHEMATICS (1)
#define SUBJECT_PHYSICS (2)
#define SUBJECTS (3)

#define STRING_LENGTH 23
#define NUMBER_OF_LINES 80

struct student
{
    int id;
    int marks[SUBJECTS];
};  struct student db[STUDENTS];

void init_db()
{
    int i, j;
    for( i = 0; i < STUDENTS; ++i )
    {
        db[i].id = NOBODY_ID;
        for( j = 0; j < SUBJECTS; ++j )
        {
            db[i].marks[j] = EMPTY_MARK;
        }
    }
}

int find_student(const int id)
{
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < STUDENTS; ++i )
    {
        if( db[i].id == id )
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return NO_STUDENT;
}

void update_student(const int id, const int subject, const int mark)
{
    int idx = find_student(id);
    if( idx == NO_STUDENT )
    {
        idx = find_student(NOBODY_ID);
        db[idx].id = id;
    }

    db[idx].marks[subject] = mark;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *input_file;

    int i=0;
    char buffer[STRING_LENGTH];
    char strings[NUMBER_OF_LINES][STRING_LENGTH];

    if((input_file=fopen("C:\\marks\\marks.txt", "r"))==NULL)
        perror("File open failed!");
    else
    {
        while(fgets(buffer, STRING_LENGTH, input_file)!=NULL)
        {
            strcpy(strings[i], buffer);
            i++;
        }
    }

    for() /*Here is where I need help with*/
    update_student();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some comments on your code.

You talk about 4 different subjects, but your code only has 3 : `#define SUBJECTS (3)`

Why would you not use an enumeration instead of defines in this case ?

```
enum Subject { ENGLISH, MATHEMATICS, PHYSICS };
```

You might want to stick with one naming convention :

```
#define STUDENTS (20)
#define SUBJECTS (3)
#define NUMBER_OF_LINES 80 // I think we all know this is a number
```

If you do it well enough, you can safely default-initialize your student "database" and write everything with correct values when iterating over the array. By doing so, you can delete NOBODY_ID as well as NO_STUDENT. However, you might want to keep EMPTY_MARK in case there is no corresponding mark (but this should not happen if there effectively are 80 *different* lines of data). You might want to keep NOBODY_ID as well if there can be less than 20 student IDs (and maybe rename it to "EMPTY_ID").

Also, when you open a file, it is nice to check for errors as you did, but you usually want to exit the program if an error actually occured.

```
// Your code
if((input_file=fopen("C:\\marks\\marks.txt", "r"))==NULL)
    perror("File open failed!");
else // You don't need this, just exit !
{
    // ...
}

// Exiting when catching an error
input_file = fopen("C:\\marks\\marks.txt", "r");
if (input_file == NULL) {
    perror("File open failed!");
    return -1;
}
// ...
```

By the way, I think Windows accepts slashes in file path : `"C:/marks/marks.txt"`

Now concerning your problem.

First, you need a way to recognize strings corresponding to subjects (e.g. "Physics"). You can simply use something like a `const char*`
Then, you want to be able to convert a string of digits to a number, probably as a stand-alone function (hint : just multiply by 10 for every new digit).
Finally, you have to isolate every piece of data of each line. It seems that, in your case, a space (or a newline) separates two pieces of data.

If you want to know the category of some character, there is a handful of functions in [ctype.h](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalnum) ; for instance, you can use isspace as a convenience for everything that seems to separate pieces of data (including the newline character) if you read your file character by character. You could also use isalpha and isdigit to verify the input, and maybe tolower or toupper in order to compare strings. However, if you only want to detect spaces, you do not need anything more than `== ' '`.

Another method is to use a function of [the scanf family](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) (fscanf, sscanf...). But only use it if you are sure about the data you read (the input format).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways, but at you level, I think you need to concentrate on walking the characters stored in `strings`, first travelling across the rows (`i`) and then walking down each character.

Make a buffer that holds your "word" in the string, and concentrate on detecting if the the word is finished (a space is read) and if not, then copying the character into the buffer.  Once you do detect a finished word, now you have characters that represent (possibly) your number or your string.

Then it is a matter of converting the right words into the right C data types.

once you have the right C data types, it should be easy enough to assign them to the right positions in the struct(s).

Answer (score 0):

uncompiled but should work with minor or no changes.
basically you sscanf the string into int+string+int, then compare the string to the options, then update_student accordingly.
btw, note that you said four subjects but have only three.

```
#define SUBJECT_ENGLISH_STR "ENGLISH"
#define SUBJECT_MATHEMATICS_STR "MATHEMATICS"
#define SUBJECT_PHYSICS_STR "PHYSICS"

int j;
int id = 0;
int mark = 0;
char subject_str[20] = {0};
int subject = 0;

for(j=0 ; j<NUMBER_OF_LINES ; j++)
{
  if(strings[j][0] == "\0")
    break;
  if(sscanf(strings(j), "%d %s %d", &id, subject_str, &mark) ==3)
  {
    if(strncmp(subject, SUBJECT_ENGLISH_STR) == 0
      subject = SUBJECT_ENGLISH;
    else if(strncmp(subject, SUBJECT_MATHEMATICS_STR) == 0
      subject = SUBJECT_MATHEMATICS;
    else if(strncmp(subject, SUBJECT_PHYSICS_STR) == 0
      subject = SUBJECT_PHYSICS;
    else
      continue; //error handling
    update_student(id, subject, mark)
  }
  else
    continue;//error handling
}
```